# calculate total count and sum of value of pandas series 7 days before today

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to calculate how many transactions (as frequency) and how much money each customer makes in the last 7 days before his subscribe date. I set the subscribe date to today to make a what-if scenario.

The code below returns:

```
d = {'count':'frequency','sum':'monetary'}
df['trx_date']=datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=7)
df['trx_date']=df['trx_date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')
diff_ = df['subscribe_date'].sub(df['trx_date']).dt.days
out = (df.assign(Before=np.select([diff_>0],["Before"],"subscribe_date"))
.groupby(['customer_code','Before'])['sales'].agg(['count','sum'])
.rename(columns=d)).unstack().swaplevel(axis=1)
final_dict = {i: out.loc[:,i] for i in out.columns.levels[0]}
```

returns a silent error.

Basically, `df['trx_date']` must be 7 days before today, and `df['subscribe_date']` is set to today.

As each customer's transaction value and frequency of purchases are different, the code should return a different result for each row.

Below is the expected output

```
         frequency  monetary
cust_code                     
6            300.0  46822.07
7            500.0  48973.42
8            451.0  51488.03
9            345.0  40883.15
10           622.0  38458.11
```

Comment: Original df would be useful?

Comment: and what is `expected input` ?

Comment: maybe first you should use `print()` to see what you get in every line of code - and maybe then you will see when code doesn't work as you expect. It is called "print debuging".